# CSS code for different background on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am really struggling with the CSS code below. I am trying to apply a different background to mobile on my Squarespace website, any help would be very much appreciated!

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(http://static.squarespace.com/static/534d398de4b0aac5146ca2c3/t/53501978e4b0d23446a58fe3/1397758328353/Textureformobile.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top center !important;
    }
}
```

Also, if anyone could help with code for bringing my site title on mobile closer to the navigation bar, again it would be very much appreciated - many hours have been lost trying to figure this out!

My site: https://katy-lockett-5lde.squarespace.com/info

Comment: Is the media query at the bottom of your CSS? If it's not then I would move it down as it would then take over.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your page. "Squarespace trial accounts are not visible to the public."

Comment: I apologise in advance - I really am a beginner when it comes to CSS. I am sure the media query is at the bottom of my CSS. This is all the CSS I have inserted:

Comment: I have CSS code for the mobile navigation, could this be affecting the mobile background code?

Comment: Is it possible that your CSS outside the media query is more specific than the one inside? Are you using an *Id* or *Class* to assign the background?